# Tag wiki edit: [algebra-precalculus] includes simplification.

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

I recently asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1919263/151595) question, which I wanted to tag in such a way that would indicate it was a very basic question about simplifying an expression. Because of [6005's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919263/simplify-a-composition-of-functions?noredirect=1#comment3939811_1919263), I learnt about the [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) tag. Can I [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/678917) this tag's wiki to indicate that the [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) tag includes questions that are primarily about simplifying an expression? As it is, "other symbolic-manipulation topics" is quite non-specific.

I don't think I can delete the [simplification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplification) tag that I created. Somebody else will have to.

Comment: About the last line (the question about deleting tags): [Deleting Tags after being created](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/deleting-tags-after-being-created)